# Stored Procedure using Select Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have a simple procedure to select data from an column and show them

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testing`
CREATE PROCEDURE `testing`(IN param1 VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN   
    SELECT * FROM testingdatabase,
END //

DELIMITER;
```

However I keep getting error 1064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM testingdatabase;`

use `;` not `,`

So it should be:

```
DELIMITER //    
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testing`//
    CREATE PROCEDURE `testing`(IN param1 VARCHAR(40))
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM testingdatabase;
    END //    
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you ! i got an error message on the mysql workbench cause i was using a query with another codes, but it worked just fine now !

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER //    
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testing`//
CREATE PROCEDURE `testing`(IN param1 VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM testingdatabase;
END //    
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testing//
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(IN param1 VARCHAR(40)) BEGIN
SELECT * FROM testingdatabase; 
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE `testing`(IN param1 VARCHAR(40))

    BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE `test_cdeo` LIKE param1;  
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You can call and check your procedure via sql command like below code

```
CALL testing('149514')
```